# How can I image and restore Windows 7 on a Intel Rapid Storage RAID?

Tags: windows-7, backup, raid

I have some Dell machines using with this card with an 32G SSD and a 2TB HDD. 
Every live environment I've tried so far has not seen the OS drive. I've tried these:

- Acronis
- Clonezilla
- Ghost
- Easeus

I have 11 of these machines and I'd really like to be able to store the image on a network share and then USB or PXE boot to restore.

DriveImage XML seems to work, but I can't see a convenient way to actually restore the image without lots of drive swapping.

I probably won't be around to run the restores when they happen down the line so I don't want to have require custom boot images with drivers slipped in. Do you think sometime in the future these cards will be default supported by the common backup companies?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. List of network cards are supported for PXE virtually unchanged. Why is this policy is unknown.

Integrate drivers into the image. This is the standard way to go.